# linux command to shuffle a large csv file to alternate rows according to a pattern

Tags: linux, csv, command-line, ubuntu-12.04, shuffle

I have a 40M+ csv file. One of the columns is a binary indicator (-1,1). I'd like to know if there is a linux command to create a new file that alternates rows with -1 and 1.

Old:

```
1,x,y
-1,t,r
-1,e,t
1,r,t
```

New:

```
1,x,y
-1,t,r
1,r,t
-1,e,t
```

Id doesn't have to follow any particular logic about how -1 and 1 are shuffled (could be random) as long as it alternates one row of each.
I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: +1 for sample data and required output, but -1 for no code:-( . What have you tried? Also note the low number of followers for many of  your tags. Consider switching one them to a programming language (awk/python/perl) or shell (bash/ksh). Good luck.

Comment: also, does the real data have an even distribution of `-1` vs `(+)1` records? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shell/awk solution. Not the most efficient, but given the speed of modern machines, shouldn't be an issue.

first, split data between pos and neg values.

```
awk '/^-/{print}' minus1Pos1data.txt > negsData.txt
awk '/^[^-]/{print}' minus1Pos1data.txt > posData.txt
```

Now merge the two files, using awk array to hold first file. you can change order if you want neg numbers as first record.

```
awk 'pass==1{pos[FNR]=$0} pass==2{print pos[FNR]; print}' pass=1 posData.txt pass=2 negsData.txt > alternateRows.txt

cat alternateRows.txt
1,x,y
-1,t,r
1,r,t
-1,e,t
```

awk evaluates the variable assignments on the cmd line `pass=1` and tests them `pass==1`? VS `pass==2`? (inside the `awk` code) and only performs the block where the `pass==?` test is true. Note that `pass=1` is an assignment statment, while `pass==1` is an equality test.

First pass loads the first file into an array `pos` with the current file's record-number (FNR) as the key.

The 2nd pass uses its current record number (FNR) to get the `pos` array rec, and the bare `print` cmd could be `print $0`, which means print the current line (from the pass=2 file).

IHTH.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using the grep, shuf and paste commands:

**shuffle1-1.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=$1

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "must provide a file as 1st parameter..."
    exit -1
fi

# split data between pos and neg values and shuffle them
# in temporary files
grep -v  "\-1" $input | shuf > tmp_subset1
grep "\-1" $input | shuf > tmp_subsetm1

# alternate 1 and -1 line
paste -d"\n" tmp_subset1 tmp_subsetm1

# cleanup
rm tmp_subset1
rm tmp_subsetm1
```

**output**

```sh
# ./shuffle1-1.sh test.data
1,x,y
-1,t,r
1,r,t
-1,e,t
# ./shuffle1-1.sh test.data
1,x,y
-1,e,t
1,r,t
-1,t,r
# cat test.data
1,x,y
-1,t,r
-1,e,t
1,r,t
```

If your file does not have the same number of lines with 1 and -1, adding `| grep 1` at the end should get rid of the blank lines:

```sh
# ./shuffle1-1.sh test.data2
1,z,z
-1,e,t
1,x,y
-1,t,r
1,r,t

1,Z,Z

# ./shuffle1-1.sh test.data2 | grep 1
1,r,t
-1,t,r
1,x,y
-1,e,t
1,z,z
1,Z,Z
```

Comment: good stuff, I didn't know about `paste -d"\n"'. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner:

```
paste -d"\n" <( grep '^1,' test.txt ) <( grep '^-1,' test.txt )
```